# Quickly navigate to document in Couchbase

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, couchbase, key-bindings, hotkeys, keymapping

Is there a way to quickly navigate to a document based on a value in a document that I'm currently viewing in Couchbase?
A few days ago a colleague was showing me something in Couch and simply held down ctrl or command or something, while clicking on a UUID in a document and was then taken to the document with that UUID.
Is there a plugin for this or hidden keybinding? I was unable to find anything by googling.. Unfortunately the aforementioned colleague is now on vacation and unreachable..

[image: Couchbase image]

In this example I would ctrl+click or something on the `deadbeaf-0011-...` value (yes I know I misspelled it) and it would take me to the document with the same title.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a feature like that at the moment that I know of, but it's a good idea.  My guess is your colleague did some URL hacking by copying the key/id and pasting it into the URL.

I'll mention this to the tools team too so they can consider that feature.  :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, he was using a Chrome plugin that he wrote to do this.  
I forked it later, here's a snippet of the code:  
https://pastebin.com/3PrU47Qq  
  
I can release the whole thing if someone is interested to work on the Chrome extension or if you just need it for reference to add the feature to Couchbase, tell me if you're interested!

Comment: Nice, I'll pass that along!